# how to merge rows with previous row when col value is empty in gridview c#

Tags: c#

want to update gridview table with merge row.

I have 3 column slno, Name, Description now if some name are blank then i want to merge with previous record ,

[old record look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTE2h.png)

How we can do like below [new record look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gT8l.png)

Answer (score 1):

We give the `MergeRows` function the `GridView` we want to modify and then we loop through each row starting from the second at the bottom up to the top.

If a cell value is `empty` we merge it with the previous one. This is done with the increase of the `RowSpan` and then making the lower cell `invisible`.

**Example:**

```cs
public void MergeRows(GridView gridView) {
    // Loop through each row in our gridView.
    for (int rowIndex = gridView.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--) {
        // Get the current row.
        GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[rowIndex];
        // Get the previous row.
        GridViewRow previousRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

        // Loop through each cell of our row.
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) {
            // Check if the given row is empty.
            if (row.Cells[i].Text == string.Empty) {
                // Increase RowSpan Size for the given cell.
                row.Cells[i].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan < 2 ? 2 : 
                    previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan + 1;
                // Set the previous cell to invisble.
                previousRow.Cells[i].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[How to merge GridView Rows (Cells with Equal Values)](https://shambhook.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-merge-gridview-rows-cells-with.html)